# WKWebView: allowing access to resource folder

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsurl, wkwebview

When you need to load into a `WKWebView` a local HTML file that references a local javascript you can use this syntax.

```
webView.loadFileURL(htmlURL, allowingReadAccessToURL: jsURL)
```

However when the html file references multiple js files included into a local folder, which is the correct syntax?

I tried passing the `NSURL` to the local folder but it is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your _which_ ? And please show what are `htmlURL` and `jsURL`?

Answer (score 0):

in that case u need to make a folder contains all the files access from html file, then add it to project, while adding to project select `create folder reference` and then get the path for the html file and load it

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myindex", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "myfoldername")
var pathUrl = NSURL(string: path!)
```

then load `pathUrl`  to web view